# get Friend.tech X (Twitter) account by their wallet address

Tags: web3py

I am currently trying to fetch new users that register on Friend.tech. I do that by looking at every buyShares transaction with the buy value = 0 as new accounts are "free" for the first one to buy (owner himself). So now I have the address that belongs to the new wallet, but I don´t know who is behind that wallet - so how do I now get their linked X account? Has Frined.tech an API for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Twitter Id of the respective wallet address, using this API:

[https://prod-api.kosetto.com/users/{address}](https://prod-api.kosetto.com/users/%7Baddress%7D)

Replace {address} with your target wallet address.